# WebDriver on building-machine

Tags: linux, build, webdriver, functional-testing

I use **WebDriver** for my java web-application.

I would like to perform functional testing there, but there is a problem: my tests use **real browser** for that - **firefox**.

So, how would be nicer to configure linux-server-build-machine to be able to perform such kind of tests there? I mean if I gut install there **firefox** like this: **sudo apt-get install firefox** would be that enough or not. Maybe someone had such experience, before I kill my server installing that.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want is the HTMLUnit driver for selenium/webdriver:
http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/HtmlUnitDriver

Comment: i would prefer to run on the server real browser instead of htmlunit fake javascript emulator..